# TFS Default Area Path set as blank and mandatory

Tags: tfs

TFS defaults Area Path for new items to Parent Area, and people forget to populate it properly, with the consequence of having items wrongly assigned to parent area (we have the children areas well specified).

I've tried to set it as blank by default, so it is mandatory to populate the value before saving the item in New state, but TFS does not allow that as AreaPath is kind of "special" field.

How could I workaround this? I'm of course open to any other alternative that can work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you said, the `AreaPath` field is kind of "spacial" field, so we can't restrict values on this field. but there is a workaround:

1) Create a new field, for example: `AreaPathValidation`.
2) Find out the AreaIDs of the restricted area paths. 
3) Make a rules to the new field like the following:

```
<FIELD name="Area Path Validation" refname="Company.AreaPathValidation" type="String">

  <PROHIBITEDVALUES>
     <LISTITEM value="Root Area Path" />
  </PROHIBITEDVALUES>

  <COPY from="value" value="No Errors" />

  <WHEN field="System.AreaId" value="54">
    <COPY from="value" value="Root Area Path" />
  </WHEN>

</FIELD>
```

The `54` it's only an example to Area Path Id, change it to your root Area Path Id.

Now when the user not will change the Area Path he couldn't save the work item :)